# Android: How to start an Activity from preference-header?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences, preference-headers

I'm trying to launch an activity from preference-header.

I searched a lot for a solution but didn't find except this question :[Start activity from preference-headers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810003/start-activity-from-preference-headers)

but when applying its answer I got a new Exception :

`android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.package.myapp/com.package.myapp.MyActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

This is my code:

```
<header
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_contacts"
    android:title="@string/menuOptionContact">
    <intent android:targetPackage="com.package.myapp"
        android:targetClass="com.package.myapp.MyActivity" />
</header>
```

I tried to change the code to many forms like this:
            `android:targetClass="MyActivity"`

Or
            `android:targetClass=".MyActivity"`

all gave me same Exception

I tried to start it from inside the corresponding fragment like this :

```
<header
    android:fragment="com.package.myapp.SettingsActivity$ContactPreferenceFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_contacts"
    android:title="@string/menuOptionContact">
</header>
```

and inside my fragments onCreate I put :

```
  startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MyActivity.class));
```

it launches the activity but when I tap back from MyActivity it takes me to a blank fragment then I have to tap back again to go back to SettingsActivity

How can I launch MyActivity directly from preference-header or get rid of the blank fragments in back tap?

**Edit**

My `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
   <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
```

any help will be very appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It been a long time but in case someone is still trying to deal with this issue,  I solved it like so
In your preference header file add this

```
<header
android:title="@string/menuOptionContact">
    <intent android:action="your custom string"
      android:targetClass="com.package.myapp.MyActivity"/>
</header>
```

in your manifest file include the following:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.MyActivity" 
              android:label="@string/my_activity_title"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="your custom string" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In my case the error is caused when I include targetPackage alongside targetClass the system end up concatenating both together
According to android developer guide both targetClass and targetPackage is synonymous to intent.setComponent method.

Comment: Thank you very much, if I had the time to test it I'll do and if it works I'll accept your answer, for now +1 for your effort. Have a nice day :)